# How can I find specific string in li>div and hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a ul list which has li's and in li there is div with no class and id. I just want to find li>div which has text saying 'Certificats et forfaits' and hide anchor tag which is next to it. Is it possible?

Here is my code

```
<ul class="select2-choices">  
    <li class="select2-search-choice">    
        <div>Informatique Électronique</div>    
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-choice">   
        <div>Informatique Électronique &gt; Accessoires Informatique</div>
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-choice">    
        <div>Mode et Accessoires</div>    
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-choice">    
        <div>Certificats et forfaits</div>    
        <a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="select2-search-field">    
        <label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label>    
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen3" placeholder="" style="width: 20px;">  
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my above list I want to find text Certificats et forfaits which is in div always and it will be always after li, once I find that I need to hide anchor tag next to it. How can I achieve this any help?

Comment: Thank you so much guys lernt alot of techniques to loop throgh thanks I will give upvote to each answer because you all are right ... thanks again]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below snippet.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).children('div').text() == 'Certificats et forfaits'){
      $(this).children('a').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select2-choices">  

<li class="select2-search-choice">    
<div>Informatique Électronique</div>    
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-choice">   
<div>Informatique Électronique &gt; Accessoires Informatique</div>
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-choice">    
<div>Mode et Accessoires</div>    
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-choice">    
<div>Certificats et forfaits</div>    
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1"></a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-field">    
<label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label>    
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen3" placeholder="" style="width: 20px;">  
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: use `.filter()` to get required div and then hide next anchor

```js
$(function(){
   $('ul li>div').filter(function(){
      return $(this).text() == 'Certificats et forfaits';
    }).next().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="select2-choices">  

<li class="select2-search-choice">    
<div>Informatique Électronique</div>    
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1">Informatique Électronique</a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-choice">   
<div>Informatique Électronique &gt; Accessoires Informatique</div>
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1">Informatique Électronique &gt; Accessoires Informatique</a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-choice">    
<div>Mode et Accessoires</div>    
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1">Mode et Accessoires</a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-choice">    
<div>Certificats et forfaits</div>    
<a href="#" class="select2-search-choice-close" tabindex="-1">Certificats et forfaits</a>
</li>

<li class="select2-search-field">    
<label for="s2id_autogen3" class="select2-offscreen"></label>    
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" id="s2id_autogen3" placeholder="" style="width: 20px;">  
</li>

</ul>
```

**EDIT** - To hide specific anchor tag, can find the anchor inside parent li like below

```
$(function(){
       $('ul li>div').filter(function(){
          return $(this).text() == 'Certificats et forfaits';
        }).parent().find('a.select2-search-choice-close').hide();
    });
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Comment: can it be specific saying a tag rather than next()?

Comment: I mean next may cause some problems if we use specific anchor tag then will be helpfull

Comment: then in that case you can have specific class to anchor tag, and then find that element inside li as parent. will it work for you?

Comment: like you have `select2-search-choice-close` class for anchor, so replace `next()` with `parent().find('a.select2-search-choice-close')` will work for you

Comment: thanks, I have added EDIT in my answer, please check

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere :  you can even select `.siblings("a")` to select  `a tag` of that particular `li`

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Contains selector**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
 $( "ul li>div:contains('Certificats et forfaits')" ).hide();
```

To hide its anchor

```
$( "ul li>div:contains('Certificats et forfaits')" ).siblings("a").hide();
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/tcd77eqj/7/)

Comment: contains may fail if div has `some text Certificats et forfaits`

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere : check my demo

Answer (score 1):

can do it with `.each()` with `jquery`

```
$("li").each(function(){
    if($(this).find("div").html() == "Certificats et forfaits"){
       $(this).next().hide();
    }
});
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fk2y892p/2/)

Comment: I want to hide next anchor tag of that div

Comment: happy coding @SudarshanKalebere

Answer (score 1):

If you know which number in the list needs to be hidden then you can use the `:nth-child(#)` selector. Here is how you would hide the anchor tag based on the code your provided:

```
.select2-search-choice:nth-child(4) a {
  display: none;
  }
```